# How can I change the ordering in JPA - Spring Framework Database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have heard that Hibernate can only create a table in the database that are in a alphabetic order.
But these questions here is over 10 years old.

How about now? Is it possible the change so JPA in Hibernate can create a table that are in correct indexing. It must be possible. I'm mean...it's 2020.

Here is a snipp of my code.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class MyTable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private float f1;
    private float f2;
    private float f3;
    private float f4;
    private float f5;
    private float f6;
    private float f7;
    private float f8;
    private float f9;
    private float f10;
    private float f11;
    private float f12;
    .
    .
    .
    private float f1000;


}
```

But the table won't be at the same indexing that the fields are, except the ID-column. It's always first to the left.

I want a table with the indexing:

```
id, f1, f2, f3, f4....
```

Comment: Why does the way that a DBMS displays a tables columns to you matter?

Comment: @Smutje Because I generate an Excel spread sheet from the database.

Comment: In that case you can set the order the columns are returned from your query, by ordering the columns in the `SELECT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the ordering of the columns shouldn't be important, and Hibernate *still may not* allow control of this, you could always make use of a different tool to manage your schemata. Two examples of this are [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) and [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/).

Both of these tools allow you to control not only the table creation, but also proper migrations as your schema develops and changes. This is generally better in a production environment anyway, since you database changes would be properly managed in your code repo, and can be tested.

Comment: Ok! I understand that Hibernate is fixed to its default ordering and cannot be changed. Thank you for the information.